# Why should a batch apex not be called in a trigger. What would be the disadvantages

Tags: trigger, batch

Why should a batch apex not be called in a trigger. What would be the disadvantages

Comment: This site is not a discussion format. The format here is *specific* Questions and Answers, and this question is off topic as currently written. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. If you edit your post to adhere to the guidelines therein, I will remove my down vote. If you are wondering for a deeper explanation to something you read elsewhere, consider linking to it for reference and expanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

You may only have 5 active batches plus 100 in queue. This means that your org will likely start giving you governor limit errors during the busy parts of the day. Instead, use @future or Queueable, which has higher limits and will likely not hit governor limits during normal system use.